# Odoo: error, when updating basic odoo modules (base, mail, web)

Tags: syntax-error, odoo, odoo-15

i try to update module "base", an error occured and loading didnt end.
[image]
i even can`t watch error description.

But i disabled loadscreen in page code and then i watched it:

[image]

```
UncaughtClientError > SyntaxError
Uncaught Error Javascript > JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
    jsonrpc/promise</<@https://erp-test-server.ta-da.ua/web/assets/2407-3bfcb27/web.assets_backend.min.js:593:55
```

i tried to find something in assets or some js module, but i failed.
also this error ocurred, when i try update other base modules, like "mail" or "web".

p.s. i didnt apply any changes to base module.

p.s_2 in this ubuntu server odoo is building in docker container.

Comment: Could you provide the modifications (code) that you have changed or added please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to update a base module is to inherit it (see documentation on official odoo webpage : https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/fr/developer/howtos/backend.html).

As Example : To update the base model: account_analytic_default:

Create your own module account_analytic_default_mycustom :

- create a new directory named account_analytic_default_mycustom in odoo/src/user directory
- Then create a `__manifest__.py` file in this directory:

```py
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
        {
        'name': "account_analytic_default_mycustom",
    
        'summary': """ my customizaton on account_analytic_default""",
    
        'description': """
           my customizaton on account_analytic_default using inherit on model and views
        """,
    
        'author': "sb",
        'category': 'Uncategorized',
        'version': '13.0.2.0.1',
    
        # any module necessary for this one to work correctly
        'depends':   ['base','account_analytic_default','account_analytic_default_hr_expense'],
    
        # always loaded
        'data': [
            # 'security/ir.model.access.csv',
            #'views/views.xml',
            #'views/templates.xml',  
        ],
    }
```

Inside your main module directory, create the basic directories : models, controllers, views, security... and create an `__init__.py` file which contains lines to import the previously defined basic directories.
Create a new file in your models directory: models.py
And in this file, to add new fields and methods to the corresponding model:

```py
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from odoo import models, fields, api
    
    class AccountAnalyticDefault(models.Model):
        _inherit = "account.analytic.default"
    
        my_newfield_startdate= fields.Datetime(string="Début réserv.")
        my_newfield_qty = fields.Integer('quantity')
        my_newfield_qty_perc = fields.Integer('quantity percent', compute='_compute_my_newfield_qty_perc') 
    
        @api.onchange('my_newfield_qty')
        def _compute_my_newfield_qty_perc(self):
            total_quantity = sum(self.env.search([]).mapped("my_newfield_qty"))
            for record in self:
                 record.my_newfield_qty_perc = record.my_newfield_qty/total_quantity
```